# How to print a parameter of a function which is used by another function in C?

Tags: c, string, hash, printing

I need to print a string(named hex) in main function. This string is a parameter of digestInHex function and that function is used in keccak function. So here are functions:

```
void digestInHex(unsigned long long state[][5], unsigned char *buffer,
                 unsigned char *bufferLocation, int bufferSize, int size, char *hex)
{
    unsigned char *byte;
    int i, j;
    unsigned long long *x;

    const char *hexValues = "0123456789abcdef";

    byte = (unsigned char *)malloc(size * sizeof(char));

    hex = (char *)malloc(((size << 1) + 1) * sizeof(char));

    hex[size << 1] = '\0';

    /* Padding */
    bufferLocation[0] = 1;
    ++bufferLocation;

    while (bufferLocation != &buffer[bufferSize / 8])
    {
        bufferLocation[0] = 0;
        ++bufferLocation;
    }

    buffer[(bufferSize >> 3) - 1] |= 0x80;

    bufferLocation = buffer;

    x = (unsigned long long *)buffer;

    for (j = 0; j * 64 < bufferSize; ++j)
    {
        state[j / 5][j % 5] |= x[j];
    }

    round(state);

    /* Squeezing */
    memcpy(byte, state, size);
    reset(state);

    bufferLocation = buffer;

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        hex[i << 1] = hexValues[byte[i] >> 4];
        hex[(i << 1) + 1] = hexValues[byte[i] & 15];
    }

    free(byte);

    // printf("%s\n", hex);

    free(hex);
}

void keccak(const char *str, enum bitLength hashValueBitLength, char *hex)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    unsigned char *buffer;
    unsigned char *bufferLocation;
    const int bufferSize = 1600 - (hashValueBitLength * 2);
    unsigned long long *x;
    unsigned long long state[5][5];

    buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(bufferSize * sizeof(char));
    bufferLocation = buffer;

    reset(state);

    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        bufferLocation[0] = (unsigned char)str[i];
        ++bufferLocation;

        if (bufferLocation == &buffer[bufferSize / 8])
        {
            bufferLocation = buffer;
            x = (unsigned long long *)buffer;

            for (j = 0; j * 64 < bufferSize; ++j)
            {
                state[j / 5][j % 5] |= x[j];
            }

            round(state);
        }

        ++i;
    }

    digestInHex(state, buffer, bufferLocation, bufferSize, hashValueBitLength / 8, hex);

    free(buffer);
}
```

As you see, keccak function uses digestInHex function at the end. hex string in digestInHex keeps the hash output of given input.

In main I need to compare my old and new project's time values using switch-case. To do this I need to run keccak 1 million times to see the time difference clearer. Not to see the hash output 1 million times I can't print hex string in digestInHex directly and that's why I made the printf of hex comment in digestInHex.

In addition I want to show the hash output in switch-case as well. But it prints null when I do it. So how can I print hash output like "4d741b6f1eb29cb2a9b9911c82f56fa8d73b04959d3d9d222895df6c0b28aa15"? Here is main:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    clock_t begin, end;
    double timeSpend;
    int n;

    printf("Enter 1 to see Old Project's time value\n");
    printf("Enter 2 to see New Project's time value\n\n");
    printf("Enter 3 to see Old Project's hash output\n");
    printf("Enter 4 to see New Project's hash output\n\n");
    printf("Please enter a value according to above: ");

iterator:

    scanf_s("%d", &n);

    switch (n)
    {
    case 1:
        begin = clock();
        for (i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
            keccakOld("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", KECCAK_256, hexOld);
        end = clock();
        timeSpend = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        printf("%f sec.\n", timeSpend);

        break;

    case 2:
        begin = clock();
        for (i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
            keccak("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", KECCAK_256, hex);
        end = clock();
        timeSpend = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        printf("%f sec.\n", timeSpend);

        break;

    case 3:
        keccakOld("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", KECCAK_256, hexOld);
        printf("%s\n", hexOld);

        break;

    case 4:
        keccak("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", KECCAK_256, hex);
        printf("%s\n", hex);

        break;

    default:
        printf("Please re-enter a correct value: ");
        goto iterator;

        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a reference to the memory allocated and set down below in `digestInHex()` up into `main()` pass a reference to the pointer `hex`.

Also adjust `free()`ing it to free it before it is (re)allocated but after it was printed.

To do so adjust the code as follows:

Change

```
void digestInHex(unsigned long long state[][5], unsigned char* buffer, 
  unsigned char* bufferLocation, int bufferSize, int size, char* hex)
{
```

to become

```
void digestInHex(unsigned long long state[][5], unsigned char* buffer, 
  unsigned char* bufferLocation, int bufferSize, int size, char ** hex)
{
  free(*hex);
```

Remove the  call to `free(hex)` at the end of `digestInHex()`.

In `digestInHex()` change all `hex` to `(*hex)`.

Change

```
void keccak(const char* str, enum bitLength hashValueBitLength, char* hex)
{
```

to become

```
void keccak(const char* str, enum bitLength hashValueBitLength, char** hex)
{
```

Leave the call `digestInHex()` as it is using just `hex`.

In `main()` define and initialise:

```
char * hex = NULL;
```

Change all calls to `keccak()` and `digestInHex)` to take `&hex` but `hex`.

Also in `main()` add a final `free(hex)` before returning.